# How to create a new database in Oracle Database 11g using SQL Developer command line?

Tags: oracle, sqlcl

I installed Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production on a Linux virtual machine. The linux machine doesn't have a desktop environment which eliminates the possibility of using the SQL Developer software. According to Oracle, SQLcl is a command-line interface for Oracle Database that combines the power of SQL*Plus and SQL Developer. I have now installed SQLcl (SQL Developer command line) and am able to run it on the linux vm.

The bin folder (inside sqlcl folder) contains the script **sql** which runs sqlcl. After running **sql**, I'm prompted for a username and password. Once complete, I see **SQL>** in the CLI.

I have found various resources online on how to create columns and tables. However, I have not found information on how to create a database using SQLcl. Is there a SQLcl command to automatically create a database? If not, what is another way to create a database in Oracle? Thanks.

Comment: Are you reallly trying to create a new database, or actually a new schema (user) to create tables under? The terms can mean different things if you've come from another DBMS platform.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed XE.... it **automatically** created a database called "**XE**". You can use your login "system" and password that you set to login.

**Key info**

- server: (you defined)
- port: 1521
- database: XE
- username: system
- password: (you defined)

Also Oracle is being difficult and not telling you easily create another database. Normally, You have to use SQL or another tool to create more database besides "XE".

Comment: With the express edition, you can't have more than 1 database.  You only get XE, you can't create a second.